# can we use old database and table with records for developing new project with custom form in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have to sign up with old project's database with same table name "user" but fields name are different, so can I signup with custom code.

So which class I have to extend, I am not using a table made Yii2 I am using my old table with records.

My model code:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

use yii\base\Model;


/**
* This is the model class for table "user".
*
* @property string $username
* @property string $email
* @property string $pass
*/

class Signup extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

/**

* @inheritdoc

*/

public static function tableName()
{

return 'user';

}

/**

* @inheritdoc

*/

public function rules()

{

return [

[['username','string'], 'required'],

['email', 'email'],

[['pass'],'string', 'max' => 50],
                

];

}
/**
* @inheritdoc
*/
public function attributeLabels()
{
return [
'username' => 'username',
'email' => 'email',
'pass' => 'pass',

];
}

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Generate new model for old table, that's all.

Comment: Custom model or through Gii

Comment: Doesn't matter, create model like always

Comment: You can always use custom table instead of yii2 provides user table, dont forget to replicate user model with your custom model. If everthing is fine, it will work fine.